# ASP.NET MVC 2: cast not valid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

[image]

And here's my DataContext:

```
[Function(Name = "Customer.spSearchDeals")]
        [ResultType(typeof(Filter))]
        [ResultType(typeof(Deal))]
        public IMultipleResults SearchDeals(
            //[Parameter(Name = "ZipCode", DbType = "Char(5)")]
            //XElement xmlString
            )
        {
            var result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this,
                ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()))
                //,xmlString
                );
            return (IMultipleResults)result.ReturnValue;
        }
```

What's the problem? What SHOULD the cast be?

Comment: What do you get if you stick `result.GetResult<Filter>().ToList()` in your Watches window? The fact that you were still able to compile the above code in order to produce that exception tells me that the problem is in the GetResult<T>() method, and not on the assignment to 'filters'.

Comment: Apparently, the results of `GetResult` are not of type `Filter`. That's all you can say.

Comment: Watch says: System.Collections.Generic.List<Domain.Models.Entities.Filter>

Comment: @dcolumbus Is it possible 'Filter' on the page throwing the exception is not a 'Domain.Models.Entities.Filter'? Check your using statements.

Comment: What you're seeing above is all but the models themselves... I have no idea what the heck the problem is! I need the results to be accesable outside of the using statement.

Comment: @dcolumbus, just a shot in the dark, but does the stored procedure return the results in that order?  Filters then Deals?

Comment: @adrift Yes, it does. if I loop through the results from within the using statement, all is well.

Comment: @dcolumbus is anything being lazy loaded?

Comment: @dcolumbus I think you misunderstood my question. If you add 'filters' to your Watch window is it a 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Domain.Models.Entities.Filter>'?

Comment: @adrift what you see above (minus the Model) is what's going on. There is nothing anywhere else.

Comment: @dolumbus One final test. Add this line and then tell me the type assigned to it after it runs: `var foo = result.GetResult<Filter>().ToList();`.

Comment: @Nathan it's the same as the rest...

Comment: Would it tell me that the type cast is wrong if the result was null?

Comment: @dcolumbus Can you show us GetResult()? I think the problem must be there.

Comment: The model had an "int" where it should have been a "long" ... lesson learned. Odd error to be thrown, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite odd...

In my model, I declared an "int" where the result was actually a "long"